# GUI FlowLayout, lock all components position

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, resize, flowlayout

I've been searching around and cannot find anything on locking the position of components in a window while using a `FlowLayout`.  I was using  `GridLayout`,  besides not liking the look of it, I wasn't able to adjust the size of the `JTextArea`.  I got everything on the window exactly where I'd like it and the correct size unless the user resizes the window then everything goes all over the place.

**Is there any way to lock the JTextArea/JButtons/JLabels so if the user resizes the window they do not move, or maybe even better lock the window so it cannot be adjusted by the user?**

Here's what I have tried:

```
public class CopyFile extends JFrame{

private JFileChooser fc;
private JButton copyButton;
private JButton chooseFileButton;
private JButton destinationButton;
private File workingDirectory;
private JLabel sourceLabel;
private JTextArea displayCopyText;
private JLabel destinationLabel;
private JTextField sourceText;
private JLabel copyText;
private JTextField destinationText;

public static void main(String [] args) {
    CopyFile go = new CopyFile();
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setSize(500, 150);
    go.setVisible(true);
}

public CopyFile() {
    super("Copy a text file");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fc = new JFileChooser();

    //Open dialog box inside project folder to make easier to find files
    workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);
    //create labels and buttons for window
    chooseFileButton = new JButton("CHOOSE SOURCE FILE");
    destinationButton = new JButton("DESTINATION FOLDER");
    copyButton = new JButton("COPY FILE");      
    sourceLabel = new JLabel("SOURCE FILE: ", JLabel.CENTER);
    sourceText = new JTextField(15);
    sourceText.setEditable(false);
    destinationText = new JTextField(15);
    destinationText.setEditable(false); 
    destinationLabel = new JLabel("DESTINATION:", JLabel.CENTER);
    //JScrollPane SP = new JScrollPane();       
    displayCopyText = new JTextArea();
    displayCopyText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
    displayCopyText.setRows(2);
    displayCopyText.setLineWrap(true);
    displayCopyText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    displayCopyText.setEditable(false);     



    //add everything to JFrame  
    add(sourceLabel);
    add(sourceText);
    add(chooseFileButton);  
    add(destinationLabel);
    add(destinationText);
    add(destinationButton);
    //add(copyText);
    add(displayCopyText);
    add(copyButton);

    //Create TheHandler object to add action listeners for the buttons.
    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    chooseFileButton.addActionListener(handler);
    destinationButton.addActionListener(handler);
    copyButton.addActionListener(handler);
}

//Inner class to create action listeners    
private class TheHandler implements ActionListener {
    private File selectedDestinationFile;
    private File selectedSourceFile;
    private int returnVal;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {



        //Selecting a source file and displaying what the user is doing.
        if(event.getSource() == chooseFileButton) {     
            returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            //Set the path for the source file. 
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {  
                selectedSourceFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                sourceText.setText(selectedSourceFile.getName());   
            }       
        }//end if

        //Handle destination button.
        if(event.getSource() == destinationButton) {
            returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selectedDestinationFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                destinationText.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());    
            }               
        }//end if

        //Handle copy button
        if(event.getSource() == copyButton) {
            Path sourcePath = selectedSourceFile.toPath();
            Path destinationPath = selectedDestinationFile.toPath();        
            try {
                Files.copy(sourcePath,  destinationPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {      
                displayCopyText.append("SUCCESSFULLY COPIED:\n" 
                                + selectedDestinationFile.getName());   
            }
            else {
                displayCopyText.append("COPY WAS CANCELED BY USER.\n");
            }   
        }//end if

    }//end actionPerformed      
}//end TheHandler class
}//end class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JFrame::setResizable(false)` to lock the window being resizable.

So your code may be like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CopyFile go = new CopyFile();
        go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        go.setResizable(false);   //No resize is possible

       go.setSize(500, 150);
       go.setVisible(true);
}
```

**This may solve your this problem**

Using fixed size is a very very bad idea. Try to use more flexible layout may be combination of layout to achieve you goal. About layout manager see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Try to follow  the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33060499/2317535) of [Hovercraft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)  .

Comment: Perfect, because everything is where I want it anyways.  Thank you!

Comment: oh ok.  I had a GridLayout but I couldn't get the JTextArea exactly the size and placing I wanted it and the FlowLayout looked and worked perfectly.  It's for a class assignment but I get what you are saying.

Comment: @sjud9227: and it's very bad practice to set sizes.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize the layout could change on different machines, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

I **strongly** beg to differ with the accepted answer, and I see some problems:

- By locking in a set size, you risk displaying a terrible GUI in all platforms (OS, display settings) other than your exact own.
- By setting a JTextAreas displayed size, you completely prevent it from being scrollable within a JScrollPane.
- By forcing your GUI to be displayed with a relatively "dumb" layout manager, FlowLayout, you limit your layout options.
- By setting the sizes of any components, you artificially constrain its size, preventing the layout managers and the components themselves from setting the best size for the components for that platform.

Instead, I recommend:

- Instead you should set the JTextArea's displayed rows and columns
- Display the JTextArea within a JScrollPane.
- Use more flexible layout managers, or often better, a combination of layouts, often used by nesting JPanels, each using its own layout manager.
- Avoid setting sizes and instead call `pack()` on your top level window after adding all components, and thereby let the layouts and the components size themselves optimally.

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CopyFile2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int ROWS = 3;
   private static final int COLS = 20;
   private static final int GBC_I = 4;
   private static final Insets INSETS = new Insets(GBC_I, GBC_I, GBC_I, GBC_I);
   private JTextField sourceField = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextField destField = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextArea displayCopyText = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);

   public CopyFile2() {
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      add(new JLabel("Source File:"), createGbc(0, 0));
      add(sourceField, createGbc(1, 0));
      add(new JButton("Choose Source File"), createGbc(2, 0));
      add(new JLabel("Destination:"), createGbc(0, 1));
      add(destField, createGbc(1, 1));
      add(new JButton("Destination Folder"), createGbc(2, 1));

      GridBagConstraints gbc = createGbc(0, 2);
      gbc.gridwidth = 2;
      add(new JScrollPane(displayCopyText), gbc);
      add(new JButton("Copy File"), createGbc(2, 2));      
   }

   private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = INSETS;
      return gbc;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      CopyFile2 paintEg = new CopyFile2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CopyFile2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(paintEg);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```